# javascript replace newlines in textareas

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `textarea` in a contact form, when it is submitted to the page that sends the mail, it passes through another page.

in the second page, when I `echo $_POST['textarea']` I get all the text in one line.

Is there a javascript or PHP code that fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at PHP's [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Example #1 from the above link:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your output page is HTML, you need to convert the lines to `<br/>` tags.

Example:

```
echo nl2br($_POST['textarea']);
```

This is because HTML treats all whitespace the same (That is: any amount of whitespace is just 1 space). (If you view the source of your page, which is usually rendered as plain text, you'll see the line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

If you are echoing it not into a new textarea, the new lines will be compressed out by the browser in the HTML. You can use nl2br() to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some JavaScript code that will do this as well:  [JavaScript nl2br](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480)